# #4 Sheepish Rebus

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, rebus

Not trying to pull the wool over your eyes...

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could this be:

> Laminate (from lamb-in-eight)?

Comment: That makes more sense than my answer :D +1

Comment: @DqwertyC:  Bravo!

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess,

Are you

> Counting sheep?

Since

> There is a 8 and a sheep.

Comment: @QT:  Not quite, but good try!